# swift: take too much time to compile dictionary literal code

Tags: swift, compilation

why following dictionary literal code takes 12Hours to compile?
obviously, myCompany has type of [String: [String: [String: String]]]

```
let myCompany = [
        "employees": [
            "employee 1": ["attribute": "value"],
            "employee 2": ["attribute": "value"],
            "employee 3": ["attribute": "value"],
            "employee 4": ["attribute": "value"],
            "employee 5": ["attribute": "value"],
            "employee 6": ["attribute": "value"],
            "employee 7": ["attribute": "value"],
            "employee 8": ["attribute": "value"],
            "employee 9": ["attribute": "value"],
            "employee 10": ["attribute": "value"],
            "employee 11": ["attribute": "value"],
            "employee 12": ["attribute": "value"],
            "employee 13": ["attribute": "value"],
            "employee 14": ["attribute": "value"],
            "employee 15": ["attribute": "value"],
            "employee 16": ["attribute": "value"],
            "employee 17": ["attribute": "value"],
            "employee 18": ["attribute": "value"],
            "employee 19": ["attribute": "value"],
            "employee 20": ["attribute": "value"],
        ]
    ]
```

Comment: It's obvious to humans; Swift needs help, so tell it.  `let myCompany: [String: [String: [String: String]]] = ...` and you'll be a lot happier! :-)

Comment: You can be specific about the type and try again: let myCompany: [String: [String: [String: String]]] = ["employees": ...]

Comment: [http://bugreport.apple.com](http://bugreport.apple.com), report the issue.